# python equivalent to listObjects in VBA for Excel (tables)

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, listobject, vba

I have implemented a program in VBA for excel to generate automatic communications based on user inputs (selections of cells).
Such Macro written in VBA uses extensively the listObject function of VBA 
i.e.
defining a table (list object)

```
Dim ClsSht As Worksheet
    Set ClsSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("paragraph texts")
Dim ClsTbl As ListObject
    Set ClsTbl = ClsSht.ListObjects(1)
```

accessing the table in the code in a very logical manner:
ClsTbl being now the table where I want to pick up data.

```
myvariable= ClsTbl.listcolumns("D1").databodyrange.item(34).value
```

Which means myvariable is the item (row) 34 of the data of the column D1 of the table clstbl

I decided to learn python to "translate" all that code into python and make a django based program accesable for anyone.

I am a beginner in Python and I am wondering what would be the equivalent in python to listobject of VBA. This decision will shape my whole program in python from the beginning, and I am hesitating a lot to decide what is the python equivalent to listobject in VBA.

The main idea here getting a way where I can access tables-data in a readable way,

[image]

i.e. give me the value of column "text" where column "chapter" is 3 and column paragraph is "2". The values are unique, meaning there is only one value in "text" column where that occurs.

Some observations:

1. I know everything can be done with lists in python, lists can contain lists that can contain lists..., but this is terrible for readability. mylist[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVbIQ.jpg)[2][3] (assuming for instance that every row could be a list of values, and the whole table a list of lists of rows).
2. I don't considered an option to build any database. There are multiple relatively small tables (from 10 to 500 rows and from 3 to 15 columns) that are related but not in a database manner. That would force me to learn yet another language SQL or so, and I have more than enough with python and DJango.
3. The user modifies the structure of many tables (chapters coming together or getting splitted.
4. the data is 100% strings. The only integers are numbers to sort out text. I don't perform any mathematical operation with values but simple add together pieces of text and make replacements in texts.
5. the tables will be load into Python as CSV text files.

Please indicate me if there is something not enough clear in the question and I will complete it

Would it be necesary to operate with numpy? pandas?

i.e give me the value of cell

Answer (score 1):

A `DataFrame` using `pandas` should provide everything you need, i.e. converstion to strings, manipulation, import and export. As a start, try

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv')
print(df)
print(df['text'])
```

The entries of the first row will be converted to labels of the DataFrame columns.